# How to configure Sphinx autodoc to document classes in __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, numpydoc

I have Python codes with NumPy docstrings. Manage to use Sphinx for the API documentation, however, classes in the `__init__.py` file not documented successfully.

Example: `xxx/__init__.py`

```
from __future__ import annotations
import sys
import re
from typing import Iterator, ...
import pyparsing as p

__all__ = ['Xxx']

class XxxData:
    """It is a class XxxData."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = dict()

    def get_foo(self, foo) -> str:
        """Get foo bar.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        foo : str
            It is just a string.

        Returns
        -------
        str
            It is just a string.
        """
        return f'{foo} bar'

class Xxx():
    """It is a class Xxx."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._something = 'something'

    def parse_bar(self, bar) -> XxxData:
        """Parse bar.

        Parameters
        ----------
        bar : str
            It is just a string.

        Returns
        -------
        XxxData
            It is a return object of XxxData.

        """
        print(f'Hello {bar}')
        data = XxxData()
        return data
```

Sample `conf.py`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',       # Core library for html generation from docstrings
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',   # Create neat summary tables
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',      # Support for NumPy and Google style docstrings
]
autosummary_generate = True  # Turn on sphinx.ext.autosummary

autodoc_default_options = {
    'show-inheritance': False,
    'members': True,
    'member-order': 'bysource',
    'special-members': '__init__',
    'undoc-members': True,
    'exclude-members': '__weakref__'
}
autoclass_content = 'both'
```

I have also wrote a function to make sure that the `sys.path` append all required dependencies.

```
docs
|-Makefile
|-build
|-make.bat
|-source
  |-_static
  |-_templates
  |-conf.py
  |-index.rst
packages
|-pss
  |-src/dd
    |-ps
      |-xxx
        |-__init__.py
```

`sphinx-apidoc` command below auto created 3 rst files: `source/api/ps.rst`, `source/api/ps.xxx.rst`, `source/api/modules.rst`

```
sphinx-apidoc -o source/api/ ../packages/pss/src/dd/ps/ --implicit-namespaces -e -M -P
```

Sample `source/api/ps.xxx.rst`:

```
ps.xxx package
==============

.. automodule:: ps.xxx
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :private-members:
```

`make html` build succeeded but with warning below:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'xxx' from module 'ps'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ps.xxx'; 'ps' is not a package
```

HMTL page rendered with empty content. I'd like to see docstrings from the `__init__.py` (sample file above) documented, but did not happen.

Technically, would Sphinx work for classes/methods docstrings in `__init__.py` file? Should I concern about those warnings that happen during `make html`?

Appreciate any insights how to configure the Sphinx to close the gaps.

Comment: How can we reproduce the problem? Are you using `automodule`? Are there any errors or warning messages?

Comment: @mzjn Apologize for incomplete question, `apidoc` auto created the rst file with `automodule`. I have updated the question with more info. `make html` has warning. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: A real [mcve] is needed. You have `from zzz.base import Base` in your code. What is `zzz`? And the question is tagged [numpydoc], but it does not look like you actually use https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io.

Comment: @mzjn That was typo, supposed to be `ps.xxx`. I just simplified `<docstring>` for this post purpose. `<docstring>` in my actual case is NumPy style doctrings. `zzz` is just another module, I have updated/simplified the example.

Comment: Do you have `sys.path.append(...)` in conf.py? You don't need a special function to add to `sys.path`. Just make sure that the folder that contains the top-level package is in `sys.path`.

Comment: I did `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))` in conf.py, the function is just an extra careful to ensure all dependencies are appended. My setup/settings work for all API docstrings except for those in the `__init__.py`.

Comment: It is not clear what `../..` refers to. Where is conf.py located? You have not provided a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @mzjn for your advice. I have revisited the `sys.path` and managed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sys.path` below works for all the subpackages/modules except for the module with only `__init__.py` file. I used `../..` because the `conf.py` is 2 hierarchies below the top-level python source file folder.

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

By explicitly append `../../packages/pss/src/dd` to `sys.path` has resolved the issue for modules with only `__init__.py` file based on the defined example of the question.

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../packages/pss/src/dd'))
```

Apparently, it is a must to address all reported warnings to get the documentation rendered as expected.

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'xxx' from module 'ps'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ps.xxx'; 'ps' is not a package
```